# Very simple Inequality of the union of 2 arbitrary events - explanation?

Tags: probability

For 2 arbitrary events A and B, why is

$P(A \cup B) ≤ 1$

I know this is pretty simple, and I understand why in my head, but what would the formal reasoning be for this? In the exam solutions I'm looking at, it says "By the difference rule" but I don't understand how this justifies it.

Thank you.

Comment: Every event has probability at most $1$. The union of $A$ and $B$ is an event. The probabilities ofr $A$ and $B$ separately have nothing to do with the inequality. No proof is needed.

Comment: @EthanBolker Consider converting your comment into an answer.

Comment: @SR810 did. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

$A \cup B$ is just another event so the probability has to be less than 1. You can think like this,

A and B are 2 events in a sample space and their union can never be bigger than the sample space. Hence the probability of their union will be less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be formal. If $\Omega$ is the sample space, then $P(\Omega)=1$. Note that 
$$
C\subset D\implies P(C)\leq P(D)
$$ 
for any events $C, D$. Indeed $D=C\cup (D\setminus C)$, whence $P(D)=P(C)+P(D\setminus C)\geq P(C)$.

In particular in your case,
$$
A\cup B\subset \Omega
\implies P(A\cup B)\leq P(\Omega)=1.$$